# Remove highlight of previously checked row

Tags: jquery, checkbox, highlight

I have a table with checkboxes on each row for selection.  Only one box can be checked at a time (similar to radio's). When a box is checked the row hightlights.  The highlight is removed when the box is unchecked.  However, when the box is checked and I go to check another box without first unchecking the first box, the highlight remains.

How can I remove the highlight of the previously checked box?

**HTML**
    
    
        
             
            Manufacturer
                Brand
                Manufacturer's ID
                Manufacturer's Description
                Pack Size

```
        </td>
        <td>TYSON</td>
        <td>BTRBALL</td>
        <td>723830124567788</td>
        <td>4.0oz Savory White Turkey Burger</td>
        <td>40/4oz</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="productMatch" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><i class="fa fa-plus collapse collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#2"></i>

        </td>
        <td>TYSON</td>
        <td>BTRBALL</td>
        <td>723830124567788</td>
        <td>4.0oz Savory White Turkey Burger</td>
        <td>40/4oz</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="productMatch" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**jQuery**

```
// allow only one checkbox to be checked.
$(".checkbox").click(function() {           
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']";          
        $(group).prop("checked", false);
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
    }
});

$(".checkbox").change(function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richbothe/gvnvzgpa/) of my code

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why use checkboxes if you want the functionality of radio buttons?

Comment: Please also post code in your question. Although jsFiddle is Jesus, we don't want to whole-heartedly rely on third-party services.

Comment: Note: atm jsFiddle is in read-only mode because of an attack. you must provide the code in question *in* the question. (edit: Thankyou)

Comment: `:checkbox` isn't a valid selector, did you mean `:checked` ??

Comment: Sorry, Just added the markup also. Checkboxes are the requirement.

Comment: updated the code replacing the selector with a class and adding the class to the inputs. Not sure what I need to do to remove highlight when another box is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method you can use:

```
// highlight row when checkbox is checked.
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
    // Highlight the current checkbox row
    $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
    // Uncheck all other checkboxes, then remove the highlight class from their rows
    $(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false).closest('tr').removeClass('highlight');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/scrowler/gvnvzgpa/3/)

Comment: No problem - for reference, there's nothing wrong with calling `removeClass('highlight')` on an element that doesn't have that class to start with. The objective here is a blanket statement saying "everything other than the rows and checkbox I select should NOT be selected or highlighted."

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

```
$(".checkbox").change(function () {

$(this).closest("tbody").find("tr.highlight").removeClass("highlight").find(":checkbox").prop("checked",false);
$(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);

});
```

Comment: I came up with [an alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nksbh4v1/), but quite frankly yours is much more efficient. +1

Comment: i was trying to add fiddle but on my pc dont know fiddle is not giving save and update option

Comment: There was a bit of code that I hadn't copied to this post that allows for just one checkbox to be checked at a time.  Seems both snippets could be combined into one?  Ehsan's solution gives me exact same result where the previously checked row remains highlighted as well the newly checked row.

Comment: @Rich i actually missed your that point that use should be able to check only one , now updated it to fit that scenario as well